# Adapter for data-biding on gridview

Tags: android, data-binding, mapping, android-gridview, android-adapter

I have a gridview

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridViewProduit"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numColumns="3" >
</GridView>
```

and I have bind that GridView with following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hdn_txt_code"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txv_des"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

       </LinearLayout>
```

And to do that , I used a SimpleAdapter like this :

```
 SimpleAdapter   produitAdapter = new SimpleAdapter(this.getBaseContext(),
                    familleItem, R.layout.affiche_famille_produit, new String[] {
                            "CODE", "DESIGNATION" }, new int[] { R.id.hdn_txt_code,
                            R.id.txv_des });
```

I will need to refresh this gridview several times, and in the documentation of SimpleAdapter it's said that this Adapter is used for static data, and it's not my case.
I'm looking for an adapter that permit me to bind my date on my gridview like SimpleAdapter permit me.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the data in the adapter changed then all you need to do is call [notifyDataSetChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) on the adapter and the grid will re-populate

Comment: I called it but it's seems to not working with simpleAdapter. And as I am said , SimpleAdapter is recommended for static data , and in my case it's not static.

Comment: is the creation of costum adapter , a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to override an **ArrayAdapter** and bind data on the **getView** methode